# How To Export Data in Excel By Using Stored Procedure In Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, database, model-view-controller

How can I use jQuery code to download Excel data? I'm using a stored procedure in the backend. Thanks in advance!

```js
function Contract_Export_Excel() {
  try {
    var dataString = {};
    ShowLoader();

    AjaxSubmission(dataString, '/Contract/ExportExcel', $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()).done(function(result) {
      if (result.Message == 'success') {
        if (result.Data.Table != undefined && result.Data.Table.length != 0) {
          if (result.Data.Table[0].CurrentState == 'success') {
            // what to write here? 
          }
```

This is my controller:

```
public string ExportExcel(string formData)
{
  // this is my controller
}
```

This is my mapper class:

```
public DataSet ExportExcelAC(ContractMapper mapper)
{
  try
  {
    SqlParameter[] sqlParameter = new SqlParameter[4];
    sqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@Company_Id", mapper.Company_Id);
    sqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Branch_Id", mapper.Branch_Id);
    sqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@User_id", mapper.User_Id);
    sqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@FY_Id", mapper.FY_Id);

    dataAccess.ExecuteSelectQueryWithDataSet("SKYBOOKS_CONTRACTSLIST_EXPORT", sqlParameter, out dataSet);
    return dataSet;
  }
  catch
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "download Excel data"? Do you mean an Excel file? Why is the return type of your `ExportExcel` method a `string`?

Comment: I have a DB Query from that query i want an excel file downloaded.Basically i need excel file downloaded through bechand query.

Comment: Export method is string because i initillize all my database components here.

Comment: like dataset,session,mapper etc